# Forcing external React component update

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a user script that modifies a third-party website built on top of React.
The user script should be able to modify the component tree. This isn't necessarily a problem, as I can change the `createElement` function to replace one component with another.
The issue is that the names of the components are minified and are being changed on every build of this website. Therefore I decided to go with the approach of intercepting the `ReactDOM.render` function to render the original component initially, then look at the DOM for the components, and using fibers to retrieve the component that needed to be replaced, managing a list of components to modify and then causing a force update using the same fiber node.

However, I can't find the fiber node. From my research, the fiber node is stored in the `__reactFiber$something.return.stateNode`; however, this property is primarily null.

Comment: Do you have access to the third party site codebase? Can you inject additional metadata as part of  each node being rendered post build?

Comment: @AnishK. Unfortunately, no, I have only the bundled js code.